# Is the QED description of an electron/photon complete?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics

Is it possible that a future theory would add more information and understanding about electrons, photons etc., or is [QED](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_electrodynamics) the best we can do?

Comment: We already know that QED is incomplete. That's why we needed to develop the standard model that includes the electroweak force and QCD. We know that the standard model is incomplete and that we may need supersymmetry or other similar extensions to make it better, and even then gravity would be missing on the level of current quantum field theory. How to include gravity is, mostly due to missing experimental data, fairly speculative.

Comment: @CuriousOne: That probably could be an answer.

Comment: @KyleKanos: It could be, but I think a more theoretically oriented person should write the definitive answer. I can only wave a giant foam hand. :-)

Comment: well, if you believe in string theory, all of the particles we know and more are just particular frequencies of vibration living on a string worldsheet.  If true, that's quite a bit of new information and understanding.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer well "if you believe in XXX theory" sounds _quite_ unscientific...

Comment: @Ruslan: there is no experimental evidence in favor of string theory, but there are reasonable theoretical reasons to expect it to be a correct theory of quantum gravity.  It stands now as a plausible model, but not a certain scientific fact.  Therefore, I embedded skepticism in my comment.

Comment: @CuriousOne I think you presented a good answer.  Make it an answer.

Comment: @garyp: Thanks for the support by everyone. Since nobody seems to want to answer in a more complete fashion, I'll oblige.

Answer (score 3):

We already know that QED is incomplete. That's why we needed to develop the standard model that includes the electroweak force and QCD. We know that the standard model is incomplete and that we may need supersymmetry or other similar extensions to make it better, and even then gravity would be missing on the level of current quantum field theory. How to include gravity is, mostly due to missing experimental data, fairly speculative.